# Flutter - Socket connection keep timed out and reconnecting by itself

Tags: flutter, sockets

The native socket server is fine. I've connected to it from other clients as well without any issues, even managed to transmit messages between clients.

And then I need to do the same from Flutter. I tried [socket_io_client](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client).

```
  Socket socket = io('http://192.168.1.2:5000', <String, dynamic>{
    'autoconnect' : false,
  });
  socket.onAny((String event, data){
    print([event, data]);
  });
  socket.connect();
```

Sadly `socket.onAny` heard nothing except timeout error with the event named `connect_error`. From server log, the client was shown as repeatedly connected to the server with new port number everytime, but without any signal of disconnection. I don't know how to keep it from timeout and even `autoconnect : false` setting was ignored.

**UPDATE**

Instead of fixing the car, I throw away the car into the cliff and buy a new car. I use [flutter_io_socket](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_io_socket) instead.

```
  Socket socket = io('http://192.168.1.2:5000', <String, dynamic>{
    'autoconnect' : false,
  });
  socket.onConnect((p) => print(['CONNECT', p]));
  socket.onDisconnect((p) => print(['DISCONNECT', p]));
  socket.onError((p) => print(['ERROR', p]));
  socket.onConnecting((p) => print(['CONNECTING', p]));
  socket.onConnectError((p) => print(['CONNECT ERROR', p]));
  socket.onConnectTimeout((p) => print(['TIMEOUT', p]));
  socket.on('connect_error', (p) => print(['CONNECT ERROR', p]));
  socket.connect();
```

And now I got clearer vision.

> I/flutter (28975): attempting reconnect
>
> I/flutter (28975): readyState closed
>
> I/flutter (28975): opening http://192.168.1:2:5000
>
> I/flutter (28975): creating transport "polling"
>
> I/flutter (28975): setting transport websocket
>
> I/flutter (28975): connect attempt will timeout after 20000
>
> I/flutter (28975): connect attempt timed out after 20000
>
> I/flutter (28975): socket close with reason: "forced close"
>
> I/flutter (28975): socket closing - telling transport to close
>
> I/flutter (28975): connect_error I/flutter (28975): cleanup
>
> I/flutter (28975): [CONNECT ERROR, timeout]
>
> I/flutter (28975): reconnect attempt error
>
> I/flutter (28975): will wait %dms before reconnect attempt 5000
>
> I/flutter (28975): [TIMEOUT, 20000]

Yes. Except for `onError`, `onConnectError`, and `on('connect_error'`, other listeners heard nothing.

Greatly appreciate the help thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugins are not for standard socket or at least they're no longer useful for that. Just use provided `Socket`.